# Auto insert keyframe ruins previous keyframes

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes

Using Blender 2.93.9. Inserting a keyframe by turning on the auto keying feature with location & rotation causes the previous frames. It's hard to describe, so I recorded a video:

https://youtu.be/Cr5clWShTWE

A bone named "Bolt" has no movements between frames 22 to 27. After I changed the location of this bone in frame 29, it ruins frames 22 to 27.

I used Blender 2.7b to make animation for over five years, which never happened to me. This annoying thing always makes me find the wrong animated keyframes each time I insert a new frame and keep wasting my precious working time.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this thing?

Answer (score 0):

At frame $22$ you have a keyframe for `Y` (brown) with value $0.09029$ but are missing a keyframe for `Y` at frame $27$ (green). So as you insert a keyframe at frame $29$ for x,y,z, value $0$ which also creates keyframe for `Y` but value $0$, it thus also effects `Y` to animate from frame $22$ with value $0.09029$ to frame $29$ with value $0.00$. You just need to insert a keyframe for `Y` at frame $27$ with the same value $0.09029$ as frame $22$ so it's brown before inserting the keyframe at $29$.